# How do I insert a blank row before specific cell values in Python?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am using the library [Openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

I have 15 functions that look identical to the one below just with different strings. I've tried combining them into a single function but this just makes the entire sheet blank rows. The only way I have found so far is to have an individual function for each of these with a break in it.

Is this the only way or is there a simpler, more efficient way to doing this?

```
import openpyxl

pws = openpyxl.load_workbook(filepath.xlsx)
pws_sheet = pws['Sheet']

def ans_call_by_agent():
    flag=False
    for row in pws_sheet.iter_rows():
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value == 'Ans. Call Distribution by Agent':
                pws_sheet.insert_rows(cell.row, amount=1)
                pws.create_sheet('Ans. Call by Agent')
                flag=True
        if flag:break
        else:
            continue
def all_calls_by_hour():
    flag=False
    for row in pws_sheet.iter_rows():
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value == 'All Call Distribution by Hour':
                pws_sheet.insert_rows(cell.row, amount=1)
                pws.create_sheet('All Calls by Hour')
                flag=True
        if flag:break
        else:
            continue
#call blank row functions
ins_agent_availability_detail()
ins_agent_missed_calls()
ins_all_calls_by_day()
ins_all_calls_by_day_of_week()
ins_all_calls_by_hour()
ins_all_calls_by_queue()
ins_all_service_level()
ins_ans_calls_agent()
ins_ans_calls_by_queue()
ins_ans_call_detail()
ins_ans_service_level()
ins_call_disconnection_cause()
ins_unans_calls_by_queue()
ins_unans_call_detail()
ins_unans_service_level()
```

The single function attempt is as follows, which only adds a single blank row at the top of the sheet and then stops.

```
def ans_calls_by_agent():
    #flag=False
    for row in pws_sheet.iter_rows():
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value == 'Ans. Call Distribution by Agent':
                pws_sheet.insert_rows(cell.row, amount=1)
                pws.create_sheet('Ans. Call by Agent')
                pws_sheet.delete_rows(cell.row, amount=1)
            elif cell.value == 'All Call Distribution by Hour':
                pws_sheet.insert_rows(cell.row, amount=1)
                pws.create_sheet('All Calls by Hour')
                pws_sheet.delete_rows(cell.row, amount=1)
            #flag=True
        #if flag:break
        else:
            continue
```

If I comment out the flag lines and add `pws_sheet.delete_rows(cell.row,amount=1)` then it will continue on but only when the `cell.value` is deleted and I'd rather that not be the solution.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what the problem is. In your title you are asking how to insert a blank row, but it appears as if you've already solved that. You also ask about efficiency, are you trying to decrease duplicate code or increase performance?

Comment: right now I have 15 functions that are almost exactly the same. I guess I just wanted to know if I could cram them all into one function instead of calling 15 different ones that essentially do the same thing. I edited the above code to reflect what I am having to do.

Comment: You said you tried combining into a single function; can you share your attempt?

Comment: I have provided the single function attempt in the primary post. If I remove the if ```flag:break```  then the entire sheet becomes blank rows and a ton of new sheets are created with the first if statement.

Comment: The single function sets `flag=True` for the first cell regardless of what `cell.value` is. Have you tried writing the function using your 2 strings as a parameter?

Comment: I would need 15 strings as parameters then would I not? The single function is only 2 of the 15 functions I have.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding. The 2 strings I refer to are the string you are comparing `cell.value` to and the string for the title of the sheet you are creating. You would call the function 15 times, but you can set your strings up in a variable to loop through them.

Comment: Why not just pass the string as an argument?? Then you only need one function..... right... Am I missing something? And if you want the comparison value and the name of the created sheet to be slightly different, as you have in your example, you could pass a tuple as an argument `(compare_val, sheet_name)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does;

```
def ans_calls_by_agent(compare_val, create_name):
    for row in pws_sheet.iter_rows():
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value == compare_val:
                pws_sheet.insert_rows(cell.row, amount=1)
                pws.create_sheet(create_name)
                pws_sheet.delete_rows(cell.row, amount=1)
                break
```

Not work?

The logic with `flag` is redundant. In your second example you have also put the `flag=True` part outside of the `if` statement, and so it will always be set to True, which you likely do not want.

Comment: That actually worked perfectly. I am pretty new to programming so when you mentioned parameters I was getting confused. I now understand and your solution worked. Thank you!